# What is wrong with my post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this post request code in jquery, which seems to send the request and get back results (I can see it in fiddler) but somehow in the webapp it is going to error and giving a empty alert. whats wrong?

```
var jqxhr =$.post("http://abhishek:9090/abc/login.action",
    { emailaddress:     e_add,
      projectid:    p_id },
      function(xml)
      {     
      /*not coming here, goes to error*/

          if($(xml).find('isSuccess').text()=="true")
          {
            sessiontoken=$(xml).find('sessiontoken').text();

            var formMainRef=document.createElement("form");
            formMainRef.action="http://abhishek:9090/abc/home.action";
            formMainRef.method="post";
            formMainRef.target="_self";
            formMainRef.id="launch";
            document.body.appendChild(formMainRef);

            var cfgemailField = document.createElement("input");
            cfgemailField.name="emailaddress";
            cfgemailField.type="hidden";
            cfgemailField.value=e_add;
            formMainRef.appendChild(cfgemailField);

            var cfgpidField = document.createElement("input");
            cfgpidField.name="projectid";
            cfgpidField.type="hidden";
            cfgpidField.value=p_id;
            formMainRef.appendChild(cfgpidField);

            var cfgstField = document.createElement("input");
            cfgstField.name="sessiontoken";
            cfgstField.type="hidden";
            cfgstField.value=sessiontoken;
            formMainRef.appendChild(cfgstField);                                

            setCookie("abcsessionid", sessiontoken , 1);
            setCookie("abcusername",e_add,1);

            formMainRef.submit();
          }
      }
)
.error(function() {
  if(jqxhr.responseText == 'INVALID_SESSION') {
    alert("Your Session has been timed out");
    window.location.replace("/abc/view/index.html"); 
  }else  {
    /*comes here, after sending request*/
    alert( jqxhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

login.action returns a small xml

```
<Response>
  <sessiontoken>4611686352224309486</sessiontoken>
  <isSuccess>true</isSuccess>
</Response>
```

Comment: Try removing the domain name, and just using relative paths like $.post("/abc/login.action", ...

Comment: @BryanMoyles: It works in that case.. including domain should be a problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the domain is an issue due to the potential of cross domain requests that the browser would block. By using relative paths, you are double confirming that the script you're posting to, resides on your local server, bypassing any potential security restrictions

Comment: scenario is I have an old webapp hosted at `http://ab:11111/abc` (which was made ages ago in c++) and and this request is sent from this page itself, some checking is done and if it satisfies the condition to go to newer version of webapp (made in totally different language java) it should go to `http://de:22222/def` webapp. Is something like this possible?

Comment: My suggestion there, would be to post to a local script, that then does a back-end curl request to the appropriate server, and returns the appropriate content. By using the server-side script as your proxy, you will bypass any browser security restrictions