# JSP redirects to another page even before button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a JSP Page which I am using to redirect to another url (cross domain), so using jQuery I placed a button click event under which response.sendRedirect should trigger, but as soon as the page loads it redirects it does not even wait for alert. What is the problem here? Please help.

on body load it calls load()

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function load(){
        <%
        String message=(String)request.getAttribute("error");
        if(message != null){
            out.println("alert(\"" + message + "\");");
        }
        %>

    }

    /*a range of options (products) based on which it decides redirection or form submission
    * will lead to the new webapp*/
    var productArray=["iirDefault","ilmDefault","mdmDefault"];
    $(document).ready(function(){       

    });

    /*Button event handler for the intermediate screen for product selection after login*/
    $('#btnLaunchCSM').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var selectedProduct=$('input[name=product_name]:checked').val();
        if(jQuery.inArray(selectedProduct, productArray)!=-1)
        {
            e_add=$("#emailaddress").val();
            p_id=$('input[name=project_id]:checked').val();
            alert(e_add+", "+p_id);
            <% 
            String e_add=request.getParameter("email_id");
            String p_id=request.getParameter("project_id");
            response.sendRedirect("http://abhishek:9090/abc/view/loginProxy.jsp?email_id="+e_add+"&project_id="+p_id); 
            %>


        }
        else
        {
            $("#launchSSO").submit();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to expect that JSP *scriptlet* and JavaScript runs in sync as you have coded it. This is not true. Java/JSP runs in webserver and produces HTML. HTML/JS runs in webbrowser. Rightclick page in browser and *View Source*. If Java/JSP has done its job right, you should not see any single line of it in the generated HTML/JS output.

You need to send a (ajax) HTTP request to your server instead. You can use jQuery for this or just a plain form submit. Or you can just perform the redirect fully in JS. Replace that smelly `<% %>` block by:

```
window.location = "http://abhishek:9090/abc/view/loginProxy.jsp?email_id="+e_add+"&project_id="+p_id;
```

Comment: I was [sending post request before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459790/what-is-wrong-with-my-post-request) but due to cross domain security it is not allowed by browsers, so instead `response.sendRedirect`

Comment: Send it to your server and have it to play for a proxy. You can of course also do a redirect in JavaScript instead.

Comment: Thanks `window.location` is just what i needed